# Removing whitespace in HTML when using a copy button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following button created to copy a template, but every time I paste it, it creates whitespace all around. How can I remove this space when pasting the template?

Code used for the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-md btn-danger" onclick="copyToClipboard('#copy')">Copy Template</button>
<div id="target" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

and the JS:

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var $temp = $("<textarea>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
```

Comment: If you mean only trailing whitespace at the start and end, then `trim`-ing the value you set for the textarea should probably do the trick. If you are talking about inter-element whitespace introduced by the contenteditable functionality(?) - then it is probably going to need something a bit more sophisticated than just a trim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, you just have to remove newline / carriage return

```
$temp.val($(element).text().replace(/\s+/g, '');).select();
```

Comment: Hey I tried this, but now it removed all the whitespace around the template as well as the whitespace in between the words. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: $temp.val($(element).text().trim();).select();